# Fatal error in joomla site?

Tags: joomla

after uploading a file in joomla site this error come

Fatal error: Cannot call overloaded function for non-object in /webcorp1/www/corpusers/p/u/punjabtourism.gov.in/libraries/joomla/utilities/simplexml.php on line 607

Fatal error: Class 'JLoader' not found in /webcorp1/www/corpusers/p/u/punjabtourism.gov.in/libraries/loader.php on line 161

anybody have solution please help

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: You shouldn't post your full path to your server, some nasty folks out there. Your site seems to be running fine for me. Is it a specific area of your site that causes this error? What file is it that you uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Disable caching and see if that helps the problem - or, if you're using APC caching, then switch to just simple file caching.